# What does "I don't have it in my heart" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I can't get the meaning of the phrase "I don't have it in my heart". 
In this context:

How many times she said, uh, first female president first female president of the United States like, it's like her gender argument. It's a great step forward, but you still have to be for the rest of the population too, like it's not just basing your election on that. Clinton, I don't have it in my heart.

Comment: Your cited text is from someone who isn't particularly articulate (one clue being constant repetition of the word ***like***). The "idiomatic standard" here is ***I don't have the heart** [**to do** something, **for** some action]*, where ***it*** in the cited text refers to whatever that action might be. The writer isn't clear on exactly *what* she doesn't have the heart / stomach / balls / inclination to do, but based on context I'm guessing she finds herself ***unable to support Hillary Clinton as a political leader***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should make that an answer. With some usage examples.

Comment: @psosuna: I didn't have the heart to closevote citing "Migrate to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)" as my reason, but you've goaded me into it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's certainly not what I suggested but I suppose that works, too, given the nature of the question. Something along the lines of "Your process is all wrong but how did you arrive at the right answer anyway?"

Comment: 'I didn't have it in my heart' is rarely used as a standalone statement, but 'I didn't have it in my heart to refuse her offer of a cup of tea, even though I was running  late'  (etc) is totally idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

**in one's heart**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85068?redirectedFrom=in%20my%20heart#eid1891211)

> in one's inmost thoughts or feelings; inwardly; secretly; at heart.

As in:

> 2001   J. Boyle Galloway Street 101   I know in my heart that in a
>   real fight he would beat the bejesus out of me.

So, *What does “I don't have it in my heart” mean?* It means *thoughts* or *feelings* as referenced in the conversation are absent in the speaker.